# JSON breaks when attempting to encode

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'll try to keep this question informative and straight to the point as best as possible.

**What I am trying to achieve**

First of all, I am attempting to get my SQL table rows encoded to JSON with a PHP script followed by some JavaScript code which gets the JSON that has been encoded and appends it to a table on my website.

**My problem**

My PHP script works totally fine, it gets data from the database **however** it only works when I've applied `DESC` to my SQL. Otherwise it breaks and I get a JavaScript error:

```
Error talking to server SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at parse (<anonymous>)
at Ut (VM1393 jquery.min.js:2)
at k (VM1393 jquery.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM1393 jquery.min.js:2)
```

"Error talking to server" is my debug output I've written in index.html

**What I've tried**

Tried to use a different browser, Firefox gives this error:

```
"JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
```

*The JSON encoder.*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include 'php/connectdb.php';

$sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column ASC LIMIT 300;");

$rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  
?>
```

Relevant JavaScript code in index.html (excluded table append etc.)

```
function getFromMySql(command){

    if (command===undefined) activity="";
    return Promise.resolve($.getJSON("jsonencode.php",{
                command: command,
        }).done(function(data){
                if (data===undefined) {
                        console.log("data undefined");
                        return false;
                }
                else if (data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                        console.log("error",data.error);
                        return false;
                }
                else {
                        // console.log(data);
                }
                return data;
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) { 

                if(status == 'parseerror'){
                        console.log('invalid json',error);
                        if (command=='saveactivity') displayError();
                        return false;
                } else {
                        console.log('Error talking to server',error);
                        if (command=='saveactivity') displayError();
                        return false;
                }
        })
    );
}
```

Sample of working JSON (limit 2)

```
[
    {
        "id": "2959",
        "alma": "991516634674702204",
        "type": "Book",
        "isbn": "0704339986",
        "author": "Zoline, Pamela",
        "title": "Busy about the tree of life",
        "dscrptn": "",
        "limg": "",
        "simg": "",
        "rating": null,
        "categories": "Refinements|Women's Literary Fiction|Short Stories|English|Font Size (format_browse-bin)|Fiction Complete|Women Writers & Fiction|Fiction|Regular Size|Lesbian|Women's Popular Fiction|Contemporary Fiction",
        "source": "bookmooch",
        "recommended": "\n"
    },
    {
        "id": "10268",
        "alma": "991516634674702204",
        "type": "Book",
        "isbn": "0704339986",
        "author": "Zoline, Pamela",
        "title": "Busy about the tree of life",
        "dscrptn": "",
        "limg": "http:\/\/images.paperbackswap.com\/xl\/89\/9989\/9780704339989.jpg",
        "simg": "http:\/\/images.paperbackswap.com\/m\/89\/9989\/9780704339989.jpg",
        "rating": "0",
        "categories": null,
        "source": "paperbackswap",
        "recommended": null
    }
]
```

**What I've noticed**

Currently I noticed that this works

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 300;
```

While this does not work for some odd reason

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column ASC LIMIT 300;
```

Further investigating has given me that the SQL commands executed works perfectly fine when outputted in a .json file, however does not output on my website. In other words, my encoder should be working just fine.

```
echo "writing data into json file...\n";
$fp = fopen('C:\wamp64\www\scifiprosjekt\scifidb2.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($rows,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
fclose($fp);

echo "completed.\n";
```

This was added to prove that there is something wrong with outputting it on my website.

Comment: can you show a sample of the working json and the non working json? (with limit 2...)

Comment: Edited original post with a working sample limited by two. @Jeff

Comment: and in contrast the non working sample, please!

Comment: one more question: does it also throw that error for a small dataset (like limit 2)?

Comment: @Jeff New edit at the bottom. I found out there is an error with outputting it on my website, not the encoder. Therefore a non-working sample cannot be provided.

Comment: Tried with Firefox and the error message it gives has been added to the post.

Comment: Do not include the php end tag `?>` in files that only contain PHP. These are very prone to errors if extra whitespace or newlines are added after it.

Comment: @Vince0789 Not related.

Comment: The issue seems to be cleared if I use WHERE and LIKE instead, but that's not a fix rather a somewhat workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by not having set the correct charset.
The charset had to be defined in my PHP file and the database table was set to

> utf8_swedish_ci

from

> utf8_general_ci

The script always seemed to crash at the first arrays which had special characters like Æ, Ø, Å etc. which then gave me the error given above in the question.